# How to decrease the space between vertical radiobuttonlist

Tags: css, asp.net, radio-button, padding

I have a vertical radiobuttonList sitting in a table.

How do I decrease the spacings between each of the listitems so that the total height of radiobuttonList is smaller?

I have tried using padding and margin but none seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `CellPadding` property of `RadioButtonList`, you can set 0 for minimum height

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlst" runat="server" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="0"  ><asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just add this inside the radiobuttonlist tag:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Width="300px">
```

Comment: The Width tag?! How is this going to adjust the vertical spacing between the list items?

Answer (score 0):

radiobuttonList in a table so try `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` and `padding:0;` for td also

Answer (score 0):

Provided this [w3schools demo](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_radiobuttonlist) demonstrates accurate markup, it looks like they're built in a table. Try this:

```
.someClassName td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Replacing `.someClassName` with the `CssClass` of the `RadioButtonList` or some other wrapper object.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the radiobuttonlist to use `RepeatLayout="Flow"` instead of `RepeatLayout="Table"`

eg:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radOrderBy" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatLayout="Flow" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="NAME" Text="Name" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="NUMBER" Text="Number" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```